# date issue after migrating to SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012, migrating

I am facing an issue after we migrated our DB from SQL Server 2008 R2 to SQL Server 2012 in our production server. When we pass any date in yyyy-mm-dd format it changes it into yyyy-dd-mm and breaking all the applications. So in SQL itself datetime parameter in SP changed our value (to yyyy-dd-mm) passed from all our applications (live website and all other backend applications).

We have tried changing `dbcc useroprions`. Currently they are set like this:

```
language    British
dateformat  dmy
datefirst   1
```

We changed it to `us-english` but it does not work. Do I need to restart DB engine?

Kindly advise ASAP as it is affecting client. Thanks in advance

Comment: What language is the login using?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms189491.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It worked after executing below SP.

sp_defaultlanguage 'DBUsername','us_english'

Thanks.